# How do I turn on debug info when building a binary using CMAKE?

Tags: c, debugging, cmake, stack-trace

I get a segmentation fault message on my command line program after building with CMAKE. I want to get the line number this error occurred at, how do I set debug mode to get back a stacktrace?

Comment: just rerun `cmake` adding `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`